# Where does Differential noise come from in a switching power supply

Tags: power-electronics, filter, noise, emc

I would like to know where does differential noise come from in an SMPS. I understand where the common mode noise comes from. It mainly comes from the fact that there is capacitance between switching voltage node and ground earth. I understand that it is noise as this input current for charging/discharging the capacitances is useless for the purpose of the SMPS. In other words, if there were no capacitances it will still work. I m not considering here the input noise that could come from external environnement. I consider that the SMPS is working in a perfect environnement without noise.

In the other hand, I have some troubles to understand where the differential noise comes from. I have a book "Switching Power Supply A to Z" from Sanjaya Maniktala (nice book !) which tells that the DM noise generator is the voltage ripple caused by the ESR of the smoothing capacitor. Here is the model : 
[image]

Here is the extract about ESR :

[image]

It is true that the ESR of the capacitor modify slightly the voltage across the smoothing capacitor. And if it modified it seems logical that the current drawn by the transformer (for example) will not be the same as if there were no ESR. So at this point, I though the noise where coming from here.

I did a simulation (simulation with no ESR and a simulation with ESR and parasitic parallel capacitance across the diode rectifier as when the frequency increase some current drawn by the SMPS can be seen at the input). My simulation may be bad...

Perfect model (ie without source of noise): 
[image]

Model with source of noise:
[image]

Here are the settings :
[image]

Here are the results : 
[image]

And finally I did an FFT of the two different currents : (Warning with the colors !!!) 
[image]

An other view : 
[image]

As a conclusion, I see that the ESR is introducing noise at frequencies higher than 100 KHz (switching frequency) but it tends to lower the "noise" at lower frequency. What does it mean ? Is it normal ? Is the 2 spectrums have the same energy ? In other words, does the higher frequency current replace the lower frequency current ? In this case, how could we consider it as noise ? In my mind, noise is something which is useless (at least in this application).

What do you think about the fact that the ESR is introducing noise ? and what about the parasitic parallel capacitors of the diodes ? When I tried to see the influence of the parasitic parallel capacitor (10nF @ a switching frequency of 100 KHz) with a model with a 1 Ohm ESR. By comparing a model with and without a parallel parasitic capacitor,  I clearly see nothing significant.

Thank you very much and have a nice day :)

Comment: Your model has too much complexity and it clouds the issue - it can be modeled by assuming the supply is perfect DC feeding via 50 uH and that there are no rectifiers involved. This is how noise is measured in practice - using a LISN - such [as this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Schwarzbeck_block_diagram_LISN.gif/1200px-Schwarzbeck_block_diagram_LISN.gif). try modeling like this and cut out all the stuff that clouds the basic problem.

Comment: See also [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/413317/how-to-simulate-the-impedance-for-this-lisn-circuit-in-ltspice) about how to use a LISN in a simulator.

Comment: You can also have a look at the [How2Power](https://www.how2power.com/newsletters/) newsletter which features an [article](http://www.how2power.com/pdf_view.php?url=/newsletters/2004/articles/H2PToday2004_design_TexasInstruments_part12.pdf) on this subject. By the way, it is important to properly size the analysis window in SPICE with the correct .TRAN parameters to match or approach those of the spectrum analyzer. I published an article in [EDN](https://www.edn.com/edn-access-02-03-97-spice-predicts-differential-conducted-emi-from-switching-power-supplie/) in 1996 about this.

Comment: As usual thank you for your links ! I will take a look on it ! I do not know how I would do without you !

Comment: Minor nitpicks: even if you want to work with idealized components, there's no need to tempt the `timestep too small` devil (or siblings). Try to avoid `Vfwd=0` for diodes (while making use of `ron/epsilon/revepsilon`, if possible, see manual for why), and setting a negative hysteresis for VCSW can go a long way. Also, `C5` and `C2` (upper side of the bridge) are not connected the way you probably want. And even a poor ideal MOSFET might need an antiparallel diode. Having said these, I agree with the comments above, unless you're looking for a more in-depth answer.

Comment: @VerbalKint do you remember a few weeks ago we talked about the slightly different position of the real peak in the bode plot compared to the pole position (conjugate poles LP filter)? Along the same lines, it can be seen that the phase angle in the bode plot when applied w aligns with the pole, is purely due to the negative pole. You probably might have realized that so just mentioning it.

Comment: @Andy aka, yes, I remember our discussion but why do you bring the subject back in this post? I haven't followed everything from the beginning here so let me know...

Comment: @VerbalKint it's got nothing to do with this post. Just mentioning it in passing.

Comment: I see, no problem : )

Comment: Thank you @aconcernedcitizen for your comment. I will have to read the LTspice manual ! There are so many things to read !

Comment: @VerbalKint, there is a problem with your article that you published in EDN in 1996 (a long time ago... ). The pictures  disappeared :( Do you have an other link ? Otherwise I will try do without pictures !

Comment: Unfortunately not : {

Comment: Thank you anyway ! :)